# Jquery slideUp on click event is not working in IE 7, 8, 9

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know that this question was asked mnay times, but I still couldn't fix it out. If you have any ideas please show me. The problem is only in IE it doesn't slide at all when clicking on the button.

here is my code

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
     $('#hide_cookie').click(function(e) {
      event.preventDefault()
      $('.cookie').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.cookie {
    background: #47515c;
    text-align: center;
    color: #dadcde;
    max-height: 115px !important;
    zoom: 1;
}
.cookie span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cookie p {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.cookie .button {
    height: 37px;
}
.cookie .button a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cookie">
    <div class="container_12">
        <span>Title</span>
        <p>content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
       <a href="#" id="hide_cookie" class="read-more">Hide me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x2r7U/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `e` as your click event parameter but then call `event`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
     $('#hide_cookie').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('.cookie').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x2r7U/5/)**

Comment: Cool! Nice job. Thank you1

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote all answers that helped you and to select one of them as the accepted answer.

Comment: Who downvoted this? Is there something not correct? Explain yourself.

Comment: Yeah who downvoted this? j08691 was first who gived the correct answer. I am waitting 40 sec and i pick this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

'slaw' isn't a correct speed value to pass to `.slideUp()`, try 'slow'

Your event function uses 'e' as the event parameter, then you refer to it as `event`

```
$(document).ready(function($){
     $('#hide_cookie').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('.cookie').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `event.preventDefault()` since it's not important in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Remove event.preventDefault() :)